# Draw only the good rect

Tags: objective-c, ios, image, drawing

I have a large image managed with `UIScrollView` and `CATiledLayer` (like the [Large Image Downsizing iOS sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LargeImageDownsizing/Introduction/Intro.html)). I had a drawing view (`UIView` overrided with drawing methods) on it in order to draw lines and rectangles.
I'm trying to find a way to redraw only the visible rect when I zoom in on the image in order to improve the performances.

I found the `setNeedsDisplayInRect()` method and I'm using it like this :

```
CGRect visibleRect = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(scrollView.bounds, CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0 / imageScale, 1.0 / imageScale));
[self.drawingView setNeedsDisplayInRect:visibleRect];
```

But in my `drawRect()` method, for now, I redraw all the lines and rectangles. How can I know which visible lines I have to redraw ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need something like this, depending on how you draw the image

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CATiledLayer *tiledLayer = (CATiledLayer *)[self layer];
    CGSize _tileSize = tiledLayer.tileSize;

    int firstCol = floorf(CGRectGetMinX(rect) / _tileSize.width);
    int lastCol = floorf((CGRectGetMaxX(rect)-1) / _tileSize.width);
    int firstRow = floorf(CGRectGetMinY(rect) / _tileSize.height);
    int lastRow = floorf((CGRectGetMaxY(rect)-1) / _tileSize.height);

    for (int row = firstRow; row <= lastRow; row++) {
        for (int col = firstCol; col <= lastCol; col++) {
            CGRect tileRect = CGRectMake(_tileSize.width * col, _tileSize.height * row, _tileSize.width, _tileSize.height);

            tileRect = CGRectIntersection(self.bounds, tileRect);

            // do your drawing
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You determine where the lines are, and then stroke them using `nsbezierpath/cgpath`, right ?

Probably, most of the time will be spent in stroking algorithm, not `determining`. Just set path's clip region to `drawRect's dirtyRect` argument. Dummy strokes should cost nothing then.